# Splitting one file into multiple files, how it will affect on performance of site?

Tags: php, html, css, performance, include

Lets say I have index.php file, in which I have following included files

```
contain of file index.php
---------------------------
include('header.php');
include('footer.php');
---------------------------

contain of header.php
---------------------------
include('cssfiles.php');
include('manu.php');
---------------------------
```

What is the performance of index.php file with above structure v/s only one file that contains whole code ?
If anyone have any link related to this, can also suggest it.

Comment: I will definitely NOT be a bottle-neck, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @Andrew, my question is - how performance of the site affected by using include i.e. including many files ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally for this type of code management, the differences in load times are so miniscule, that the benefits of using such a system outweighs the performance load. I would encourage anyone to look into MVC models for better code management.

The only way you'd see a performance spike is if you had hundreds of files, and then I'd implore you to look at `__autoload()`. But From what you've posted there, it looks like a fairly standard and common practice for PHP developers.

You can read [this](http://gen5.info/q/2009/01/09/an-awesome-autoloader-for-php/) for a bit of clarity if you still need more information.